# Is it right to use a class' methods to update an instance of the class' variables? If it is, how do I do it?

Tags: python, json, oop, object

I have the following code;

```
class weather(object):
temperature = 0
humidity = 0
precis = "There is no weather when there plainly should be, please contact an administrator."
cloud = "none"
windDirection = "nnw"
windSpeed = 0

def getWeather(self):
    weatherJSON = requests.get('http://www.bom.gov.au/fwo/IDT60901/IDT60901.94970.json')
    weatherDoc = json.loads(weatherJSON.text)
    temperature = weatherDoc["observations"]["data"][1]["apparent_t"]
    humidity =  weatherDoc["observations"]["data"][1]["rel_hum"]
    windDirection = weatherDoc["observations"]["data"][1]["wind_dir"]
    windSpeed = weatherDoc["observations"]["data"][1]["wind_spd_kmh"]
    cloud = weatherDoc["observations"]["data"][1]["cloud_type"]
```

This is a class that has weather features, and contains a function to update them.  If I then instantiate the class with

```
this = weather()
this.getWeather()
```

The variables in this don't get updated with real world weather.  Two questions, why not, and I guess as more of a sub-question, am I doing this right?  Should my approach be to use the methods in a class to manipulate an instance of the class?

Comment: As a side note, you really should use consistent indentation, not 2 spaces sometimes, 4 spaces other times. It makes your code a lot easier to read, and to maintain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got two fundamental problems here.

---

First, you're mixing up *class attributes*—that is, variables that are shared by all instances of the same class—and normal *instance attributes*—that is, variables that are a part of each instance.

You very rarely want class attributes for anything. You want instance attributes, however, all the time. So, to start with:

```
class weather(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.temperature = 0
        self.humidity = 0
        self.precis = "There is no weather when there plainly should be, please contact an administrator."
        self.cloud = "none"
        self.windDirection = "nnw"
        self.windSpeed = 0
```

Notice the `self.temperature`, not just `temperature`. That's how you create an instance attribute. It's also how you access or update one.

---

Second, you're also mixing up *local variables*—that is, variables that exist while a function is running and then disappear—with instance attributes. But you already know hot to update instance attributes from above. So:

```
def getWeather(self):
    weatherJSON = requests.get('http://www.bom.gov.au/fwo/IDT60901/IDT60901.94970.json')
    weatherDoc = json.loads(weatherJSON.text)
    self.temperature = weatherDoc["observations"]["data"][1]["apparent_t"]
    self.humidity =  weatherDoc["observations"]["data"][1]["rel_hum"]
    self.windDirection = weatherDoc["observations"]["data"][1]["wind_dir"]
    self.windSpeed = weatherDoc["observations"]["data"][1]["wind_spd_kmh"]
    self.cloud = weatherDoc["observations"]["data"][1]["cloud_type"]
    self.precis = '???'
```

(I'm not sure what you want to put in `precis`, but clearly you don't want to leave it as "There is no weather…".)

---

If you make the second fix without the first, everything will *appear* to work, but only by coincidence. When you ask for `this.temperature`, if `this` has no instance attribute named `temperature`, Python will automatically look for the class attribute `type(this).temperature`. If you then add an instance attribute named `temperature`, it "shadows" the class attribute, so next time you do `this.temperature`, you get the instance's value.

So, you *can* use class attributes as a sort of "default value" for instance attributes. But you should only do this if you know what you're doing. (It can get really confusing if, say, you start using mutable values like lists and mutating them in your methods…)

Answer (score 0):

> Two questions, why not, and I guess as more of a sub-question, am I doing this right?

You're updating a local variable in getWeather().

You should update the instance variable instead, which can be done by prefixing the variable name with self, in other words, replace:

```
def getWeather(self):
    ...
    cloud = ...
```

with

```
def getWeather(self):
    ...
    self.cloud = ...
```

Answer (score -1):

Is the indentation in your example broken? Are those variables supposed to be class members of the weather class?

Eitherway, the function is **shadowing** them, creating new ones locally and therefore not changing the others.

Comment: This isn't really an answer, asking for clarification might be better done as a comment

Comment: Also, the function isn't actually shadowing the class attributes.